# How to Find Time Since Last Game Played by a Team in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset that contains matchups of teams, and each team can be either team1 or team2 for any given matchup, I am looking to write a pandas function to create the following table which keeps track of how long it has been since the last game played by that team.

| team.id_team1 | team.id_team2 | game.date | time_since_last_team1 | time_since_last_team2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 23 | 2007-11-03 | NaT | NaT |
| 2 | 28 | 2007-11-03 | NaT | NaT |
| 18 | 20 | 2007-11-03 | NaT | NaT |
| 23 | 4 | 2007-11-04 | 1 | NaT |
| 7 | 2 | 2007-11-05 | NaT | 2 |
| 28 | 3 | 2007-11-05 | 2 | 2 |
| 18 | 3 | 2007-11-06 | 3 | 1 |

I have made many attempts but none worth mentioning, the main problem that I am encountering is that the team doesn't stay in one column.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi @Alex, welcome to SO. Do you need 2 `id_team` columns in your output or just one ? Wouldn’t it make more sence yo have just `id_team` / `game.date` / `time_since_last_game` ? Also, can you show your initial dataset with the matchup of teams as well ?

Comment: Hi! @Cimbali I do need the 2 column IDs, this dataset is an aggregate of 2 teams statistics used for a machine learning model I am working on. The rest of the dataset is 145 different columns so it's pretty hard to post. For the purposes of this problem through the output does also need to be in 2 separated columns, since the time since last game for each team will be different. I need all the entries to be in one row to be ingested by the ML model.

Comment: At least show us the relevant columns in the input dataset @Alex. As you see in my answer I’m having to guess what the inputs look like. For the ouputs: every time a team appears it should have the same `time_since_last` no ? So in your example the first row `time_since_last_team1` and 2 last rows `time_since_last_team2` should be the same value − all corresponding to `team.id = 3`, is that correct ? Or do you want the time between games for each team, instead of the time since the last game ?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from this `games` dataframe (with `game.date` a datetime columns), and a current date `curdate`:

```
>>> games
   team.id_team1  team.id_team2  game.date
0              3             23 2007-11-03
1              2             28 2007-11-03
2             18             20 2007-11-03
3             23              4 2007-11-04
4              7              2 2007-11-05
5             28              3 2007-11-05
6             18              3 2007-11-06
>>> games.dtypes
team.id_team1             int64
team.id_team2             int64
game.date        datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
>>> curdate = pd.Timestamp.today().floor(freq='D')
>>> curdate
Timestamp('2021-06-15 00:00:00')
```

Now get for each column the last games, then join them and get the max per team id

```
>>> last_game_1 = games.groupby('team.id_team1')['game.date'].max()
>>> last_game_2 = games.groupby('team.id_team2')['game.date'].max() 
>>> last_game = pd.concat([last_game_1, last_game_2]).groupby(level=0).max()
>>> df = last_game.rename_axis('team.id_team').reset_index()
>>> df
   team.id_team  game.date
0             2 2007-11-05
1             3 2007-11-06
2             4 2007-11-04
3             7 2007-11-05
4            18 2007-11-06
5            20 2007-11-03
6            23 2007-11-04
7            28 2007-11-05
```

Finally get the days between `curdate` and the date column:

```
>>> df['days_since_last_game'] = (curdate - df['game.date']).dt.days
>>> df
   team.id  game.date  days_since_last_game
0        2 2007-11-05                  4971
1        3 2007-11-06                  4970
2        4 2007-11-04                  4972
3        7 2007-11-05                  4971
4       18 2007-11-06                  4970
5       20 2007-11-03                  4973
6       23 2007-11-04                  4972
7       28 2007-11-05                  4971
>>>
```

Now if I understand what you need well, join can join this time since last game back with the input columns you’re interested in:

```
>>> games.merge(df[['team.id_team', 'days_since_last_game']].add_suffix('1'), on='team.id_team1')\
...      .merge(df[['team.id_team', 'days_since_last_game']].add_suffix('2'), on='team.id_team2')
   team.id_team1  team.id_team2  game.date  days_since_last_game1  days_since_last_game2
0              3             23 2007-11-03                   4970                   4972
1              2             28 2007-11-03                   4971                   4971
2             18             20 2007-11-03                   4970                   4973
3             18              3 2007-11-06                   4970                   4970
4             28              3 2007-11-05                   4971                   4970
5             23              4 2007-11-04                   4972                   4972
6              7              2 2007-11-05                   4971                   4971
```

Comment: This does bring up an idea of potentially having a second dataframe as sort of a map to keep track of each team's most recent games, and tally the time difference with a new game. I can maybe pull from this new dataset the days since last game for each entry? @Cimbali